# How to show: Matrix $H_v = I - 2vv^{\top}$ with $||v|| =1$ to the reflection on hyperplane $v^{\bot}$ is symetrical and orthogonal and $det H_v = -1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonal-matrices, transpose

I have several questions

1. How can I show that a Matrix $H_v = I - 2vv^{\top}$ with $||v|| =1$ to the reflection on the hyperplane $v^{\bot}$ is symetrical and orthogonal and the determinant is $det H_v = -1$?\
2. And is every symetrical orthogonal matrix  $A$ with $A = -1$ formed $A=H_v$ for a $v$?
3. How to show that every orthogonal matrix $A$ is a product of reflection matrices $H_v$ on the hyperplane $v^{\bot}$
4. How can one describe every quadratic upper triangular matrices $A$ which are orthogonal?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, matrices of the form $I - uv^T$ are asked about extensively on this site, did you try searching those posts for the answers you want?

Comment: I would not even know where to start atm. I'd appreciate the smallest hint. Also: I didn't find anything close to this. How can I improve searching on this site?

Comment: My [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3605489/81360) is related.

Comment: What do you mean by "show that $H_v$... to the reflection"? Do you mean that you want to show that $H_v$ **is the matrix associated with** the reflection on the hyperplane $v^\perp$?

Comment: Or, is your first question suppose to be "show that the matrix $H_v$ (which is associated with the reflection...) is symmetrical and orthogonal with determinant -1"?

Comment: if I understood it correctly $||v||=1$ is the euclidean norm, so the distance to the reflection in the origin hyperplane is 1. so, yes, i think?

Comment: well, I think i can answer 4. by myself now: to be orthogonal, A must have the property $AA^{\top}=I$ so $A^{\top}$ must be $A^{-1}$. But the Inverse of a upper triangular matrix can't be its transpose, because the inverse must be another upper triangular matrix.So there can't be any othogonal triangular upper matrices. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to work a bit on it, and with the help of other answers on this board I came up with some answers:

1. $I$ is symetric. The dot product §vv^{\top}§ gives a symmetric matrix as result. The $2$ in front is irrelevant. It's a mutpile so that still counts. 
   It is $(AB)^{\top} = B^{\top} A^{\top} $, so $I^{\top} = I$ and
   $(vv^{\top})^{\top} = vv^{\top}$. And with that $H^{\top} = (I-
   vv^{\top})^{\top} = I^{\top} - (vv^{\top})^{\top} = I - vv^{\top} = H$.
   $H$ is therefor symmetrical.
2. counter example matrix [-1 0 0; 0 -1 0; 0 0 -1]
3. Let $u,v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ be colmn vectors, their dot product is then $\langle u,v \rangle = u^{\top} \cdot v$. Let $A$ be a orthogonal Matrix, then:

$\langle A \cdot u,A \cdot v \rangle = (A \cdot u)^{\top} \cdot (A \cdot v) = u^{\top} \cdot A^{\top} \cdot A \cdot v = u^{\top} \cdot A^{-1} \cdot A \cdot v = u^{\top} \cdot v$
This shows that the transformation keeps the dot product. no change of angles is happening. This is in general the product of reflections. Bonus: Every reflection can be made with a series of householder reflections. So it is about householder reflections and matrices, too.

4. There are no upper triangular matrices which are orthogonal. Under the main diagonal there are only zeros, and multiplied with another upper tirangular matrix, the result will again be an upper triangular matrix. Thus the Inverse of the upper triangular matrix $R$ is an upper triangular matrix. The transpose on the other hand is an lower triangular matrix  $R^{\top} = L$
   But from that follows $R^{\top} \neq R^{-1}$